# Regarding smallest $ \sigma $ algebra containing a set A and $ \pi $ system

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to solve a problem in measure theory but i have no clue on how to proceed on this problem can somebody please help.

Problem is - let C be a  $ \pi $  system and define $ \lambda $ (C) to be intersection of all $ \lambda  $ systems containing C. Also, let $ \sigma $ (C) to be smallest $ \sigma $ algebra containing C . 
Prove that $ \lambda $ (C) = $ \sigma $(C) .

Comment: 1. A $\sigma$-algebra is a $\lambda$-system which is also a $\pi$-system. 2. Prove that $\mathcal L= \{A\in \lambda(C): \forall B\in C\ A\cap B \in \lambda(C)\}$ is a $\lambda$-system. 3. Prove the same about $\mathcal L'= \{A\in \lambda(C): \forall B\in \lambda(C)\ A\cap B \in \lambda(C)\}$. 4. Conclude.

Comment: @zhoraster  I proved first 3 parts but I am not able to conclude what I had to prove. Can you please explain 4 th part of your answer.

Comment: 2 and 3 imply that $\lambda(C)$ is a $\pi$-system, hence, it is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: This  is Dynkin's $\pi - \lambda$ Theorem and a proof can be found in many books as well as Wikipedia.